# The .on('click') jquery event doesn't work on a dynamic list box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

I'd like to know why, and how to solve it, when I click on an option of my multiple list box...

`$(document).on("click, id", function () {
    //some code
});`

doesn't work

Here is my html code

```
<div class="box">
  <div class="input-group">
   <div class="text-primary">
     Select something
      <select name="boxAgents" class="form-control" id="boxAgents" size="5">
        </select>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

When that list box is filled with some dynamic data obtained from ajax like this

```
$.each(res, function (index, item) {
   var listAgents = item.agentName;    
   $("#boxAgents").append('<option id="agent' + listAgents + '" value="' + listAgents + '">' + listAgents + '</option>');
});
```

I'd like that when I click an option in my "boxAgents" list, pass it to another list box.
I try to pass the options this way

```
$(document).on("click", "option[id^='agent']", function () {
        var id = $(this).attr("id").replace("agent", "");
        $("#boxSelectedAgen").append('<option id="remove"' + id + ' value="' + id + '">' + id + '</option>');
    });
```

The funny thing is that my code only works if I remove the "`size=5`" from the select tag, it doesn't work if I use "`multiple=multiple`" neither. It only works if my "boxAgents" is a normal dropdown list.

What should I do?

Comment: Try this, `$('#boxAgents').on('click', 'option', function(){.....}`.  You don't want to bind to the entire document as you did if at all avoidable.

Comment: Is it supposed to function like [this](http://plnkr.co/edit/fNkOZinUS2HVSAdsxJX8?p=preview)? If not, please provide a sample demonstrating the issue...

Comment: sorry, it doesn't work, if I go that way, it will append any selected option from the web page to "boxAgents", thats why I was using selectors to extract a portion of the id

Comment: let me try it, Sam, thanks... I'll let you know

Comment: I'm so sorry, Sam, I though It already contained the jquery code, if there is the code, I'm not able to see it... But, yes, it should work like that.

Comment: I just realized that the code how it is showed in the question, works just fine only on firefox... And Sam, I already saw the script.js file, I see no difference between your code and mine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, I did it, I solved it using another method... I used

```
$('#boxAgent').change(function(){ 
    var value = $(this).val();
    $("#boxSelectedAgen").append('<option id="remove"' + value + ' value="' + value + '">' + value + '</option>');
});
```

And it moves the options to the another multiple text box.

Thank you all for your support guys!.